# Spring boot JUNIT test fails for service test

Tags: spring-boot, junit4

I am trying to perform a Junit 4 test from a service in a spring boot application and I keep getting an entityManagerFactory its with init.

I also want connect using my application.properties file, but it wants to connect using the embedded hsqldb.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Below is the pertinent code:

APPLICATION.PROPERTIES:

```
    # ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "netgloo_blog"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finra?useSSL=false

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = finra
spring.datasource.password = finra

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

MAIN:

```
    package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.entity"})
//@ImportResource("classpath:application.properties")
//@Configuration
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ComponentScan
//@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ENTITY:

```
    package com.example.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface UserInterface extends Serializable{
    public long getId();
    public long setId(long value);
    public String getEMail();
    public void setEmail( String value );
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String value);
}

    package com.example.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
//import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
//@Table(name = "users")
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})
        }
)
public class User implements UserInterface {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -507606192667894785L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public long setId(long value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEMail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEmail(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        email = value;

    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        name = value;

    }

}
```

DAO/REPOSITORY:

```
    package com.example.dao;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.entity.User;

@Transactional
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByEmail( String email );
    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao);

}
```

SERVICE:

```
    package com.example.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.entity.User;

@Service("userService")
public class UserService {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger (this.getClass());

    @Autowired UserDao userDao;

    public void setUserDao( UserDao userDao ){
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public List<User> findAll(){
        return (List<User>) userDao.findAll();
    }

    public User findOne( long id ){
        return userDao.findOne(id);
    }

    public User getByEmail(String email) throws Exception{

        String userId = null;
        User user = null;
        try{
            user = userDao.findByEmail(email);
            userId = String.valueOf(user.getId());
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("User not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        log.info("The user id is: " + userId);
        return user;        
    }

    public User create( String email, String name ){
        User user = null;
        try{
            user = new User();
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setName(name);
            userDao.save(user);
        }catch( Exception e ){
            log.error("Error creating the user: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("User id: " + user.getId() + " saved.");
        return user;
    }

    public User updateUser(long id, String email, String name ){
        User user = null;
        try{
            user = userDao.findOne(id);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setName(name);
            userDao.save(user);
        }catch( Exception e ){
            log.error("Error updating the user: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return user;
    }

    public User delete( long id ) throws Exception{
        User user = null;

        user = userDao.findOne(id);
        userDao.delete(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

TEST:

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.example.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.DemoApplication;
import com.example.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.entity.User;

/**
 * @author denisputnam
 *
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class)
//@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//@SpringBootConfiguration
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    private UserService userService;

//  @Autowired
//  public void setUserService( UserService userService ){
//      this.userService = userService;
//  }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {


//      userDao = EasyMock.createMock(UserDao.class);
//
        userService = new UserService();
        userService.setUserDao(userDao);
//      testEntityManager = new TestEntityManager(emf);
//      this.testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
//      this.testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
    }

    /**
     * Test method for {@link com.example.service.UserService#findAll()}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testFindAll() {
//      EasyMock.reset(userDao);
//      final List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
//      EasyMock.expect(userDao.findAll()).andReturn(users);
//      EasyMock.replay(userDao);
//      EasyMock.verify(userDao);
//      Assert.notEmpty(users, "findAll() failed.");
//      User user = new User();
//      user.setEmail("bogus@bogus.com");
//      user.setName("bogus");
//      UserService userService = new UserService();
//      this.setUserService(userService);
        User user = this.userService.create("bogus@bogus.com", "bogus");
        final List<User> users = (List<User>) this.userDao.findAll();
        Assert.notEmpty(users, "Found no users.");

    }

    /**
     * Test method for {@link com.example.service.UserService#findOne(long)}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testFindOne() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Test method for {@link com.example.service.UserService#getByEmail(java.lang.String)}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetByEmail() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Test method for {@link com.example.service.UserService#create(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Test method for {@link com.example.service.UserService#updateUser(long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testUpdateUser() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Test method for {@link com.example.service.UserService#delete(long)}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDelete() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

SHOULD HAVE INCLUDED THIS:

```
    2017-04-02 16:30:00.627  INFO 93661 --- [           main] com.example.service.UserServiceTest      : Starting UserServiceTest on Deniss-IMAC.home with PID 93661 (started by denisputnam in /Users/denisputnam/git/springboot/demo)
2017-04-02 16:30:00.627  INFO 93661 --- [           main] com.example.service.UserServiceTest      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-02 16:30:00.630  INFO 93661 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@3111631d: startup date [Sun Apr 02 16:30:00 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-02 16:30:00.694  INFO 93661 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'userService' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.example.service.UserService]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [/Users/denisputnam/git/springboot/demo/target/classes/com/example/service/UserService.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=userServiceTest.Config; factoryMethodName=userService; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/example/service/UserServiceTest$Config.class]]
2017-04-02 16:30:00.705  INFO 93661 --- [           main] beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
2017-04-02 16:30:00.705  INFO 93661 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-04-02 16:30:00.705  WARN 93661 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'embeddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2017-04-02 16:30:00.740  INFO 93661 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:77b77b83-0034-41be-ab58-3f5d9490ea80', username='sa'
2017-04-02 16:30:00.805  INFO 93661 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-04-02 16:30:00.805  INFO 93661 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-04-02 16:30:00.810  INFO 93661 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-04-02 16:30:00.825  INFO 93661 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2017-04-02 16:30:00.827  INFO 93661 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: user
2017-04-02 16:30:00.828  INFO 93661 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: user
2017-04-02 16:30:00.829  WARN 93661 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-04-02 16:30:00.829  INFO 93661 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
```

STACK:

```
    2017-04-02 16:05:44.625 ERROR 92739 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

[spring boot configuration example](https://github.com/RadouaneRoufid/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-multi-database-tutorial)